# Stock calculation in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table named Stock

```
ID | Plant | Item | Quantity
1    1      Pepsi    1
2    1      Coke     3
3    2      Pepsi    5
```

How to reconstruct previous state to get this result?

```
ID | Plant | Item | Quantity | THIS(total_stock)
1    1      Pepsi    1              6
2    1      Coke     3              3
3    2      Pepsi    5              6
```

Comment: I rolled back your edit where you replaced the nicely formatted plain text sample data with images. Showing sample data as images is frowned upon, using formatted text is way better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can be done using a window function:

```
select id, plant, item, quantity, 
       sum(quantity) over (partition by item) as total_stock
from stock;
```